# Find nonzero rgb pixels efficiently python

Tags: python, numpy

I have RGB images in NumPy `ndarray` (width, height, rgb) format (i.e (1370, 5120, 3) ). I want to find an efficient way to get the x, y coordinates of nonzero rgb valued pixels. Instead of doing for loop to iterate over each pixel, I'm looking for a vectorized implementation by using a numpy method such as `any` or `nonzero` maybe (because I have over 30k images). Can someone help me out by giving some examples of possible implementations?

Comment: nonzero_mask = np.all(image_arr != [0, 0, 0], axis=-1);   nonzero_indices = np.where(mask == True)

Answer (score 0):

Looking for black pixel is same as looking for pixels with `r + g + b == 0`.

```py
import numpy as np

# Make fake data for testing
# 0th axis: x
# 1st axis: y
# 2nd axis: r, g, and b

size = (1370, 5120, 3)
# allocate new memory for the array (slow)
# fill the new array with random integer (vectorized c loop, medium speed)
img = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=size, dtype=np.uint8)

# allocate new memory for the s array         (slow)
s = np.sum(img, axis=2)    # sum              (vectorized c loop, fastest)
                           # sum on last axis is fastest because that adds
                           # up numbers next to each other in the memory.
# allocate new memory for the non_black array (slow)
non_black = (s != 0)       # comparison       (vectorized c loop, fast)
# allocate new memory for the x, y arrays     (slow)
x, y = np.where(non_black) # scan & convert   (c loop, slower)

print(x, y)
```

Allocating memory for the `img` array is slow. But loading the `img` from hard disk is horribly slow compared to allocation of the memory.

If you don't do a lot of computation on the images, then compression of the image / fast solid state hard drive would be a major factor in speed of the process. If computation and IO take roughly same amount of time, use one thread to load the data from hard disk while another thread does the computation.

Direct transformation of the `img` array is often faster than working with the coordinates if you have enough memory for holding the `img` array. Transforming the `img` in-place is even faster because that avoids allocating new memory for the result.

Coordinates use less memory if the img contains lots of black pixels. That might be fine if you are working with black/white image. Try sparse matrix if you have lots of black pixels and memory is an issue.

Comparison is slower than sum. Probably can replace the comparison with a conversion from int to boolean.

The `np.all(image_arr != [0, 0, 0], axis=-1)` method requires 3 comparisons and 1 logical_and per pixel and generates two intermediate arrays that are as large as the image. The method here needs 1 sum and 1 comparison per pixel and generates two intermediate arrays that are smaller than the image.

But all these optimization of the computation is pointless if the I/O takes eternity compared to the computation time.

Comment: Why do you need the coordinate? Can you just transform the image?

Comment: Quality answers generally include an explanation, adding context, insight, understanding, and long-term value so visitors can apply the you're knowledge to their own issues. Most upvotes come from future visitors facing similar issues, looking for insight, knowledge, & solutions.